# How to prevent registration of DLL in the GAC

Tags: windows, dll

I have a dll say DLLA(Version3) installed in GAC. 
When a lower version of the same dll ,say DLLA(version 2) is trying to install into GAC, I need to prevent it because there is already an higher version of the same in GAC.
How do I do this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, the point of the GAC is to store multiple versions of a DLL side-by-side.  You can't turn off a core feature like this.  If you want to create DLL Hell then just don't use the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

The GAC will manage multiple versions of the same DLL, this is not a problem.